# Polyline and spline in QGraphicsView

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I want to draw polyline in qgraphicsview in qt. I am able to draw Line but want to draw polyline and spline in qgraphicsview. I am having different class for each entity. Can anybody guide me how to proceed for the same?

Answer (score 2):

Do not reinvent the wheel.

Simply use [QGraphicsPathItem](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/QGraphicsPathItem.html) and update its [shape](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qgraphicspathitem.html#shape). [QPainterPath](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qpainterpath.html#details) has all functionality you need.

Comment: Can you please explain me in detail about this as I dont have any idea how to implement above two shapes.

Answer (score 0):

```
qpp = QPainterPath()
qpp.addPolygon(your_polyline)
item = QGraphicsPathItem(qpp)
item.setPen(your_pen)
self.your_scene.addItem(item)
```